# How can I provide a header or a footer for an MvxCollectionViewController?

Tags: xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm attempting to provide a header and footer view from within an MvxCollectionViewController and I am having trouble. Normally, with a UICollectionViewController, I would override the GetViewForSupplementaryElement method like so:

```
public override UICollectionReusableView GetViewForSupplementaryElement (UICollectionView collectionView, NSString elementKind, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var someHeaderOrFooterView = (HeaderOrFooterView) collectionView.DequeueReusableSupplementaryView (elementKind, elementId, indexPath);
    return someHeaderOrFooterView;
}
```

MvxCollectionViewControllers don't seem to get delegate callbacks to the GetViewForSupplementaryElement method like a UICollectionViewController does.

Is there another method for specifying the header and footer of a CollectionView using MvxCollectionViewController?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard steps should work (they work here...):

1. Provide a size for the header in the layout

   ```
       HeaderReferenceSize = new System.Drawing.SizeF(100, 100),
   ```
2. Implement a class for the header

   ```
   public class Header : UICollectionReusableView
   {
       UILabel label;

       public string Text
       {
           get { return label.Text; }
           set { label.Text = value; SetNeedsDisplay(); }
       }

       [Export("initWithFrame:")]
       public Header(System.Drawing.RectangleF frame)
           : base(frame)
       {
           label = new UILabel() { Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, 0, 300, 50), BackgroundColor = UIColor.Yellow };
           AddSubview(label);
       }
   }
   ```
3. register that class

   ```
      CollectionView.RegisterClassForSupplementaryView(typeof(Header), UICollectionElementKindSection.Header, headerId);
   ```
4. Implement GetViewForSupplementaryElement

   ```
   public override UICollectionReusableView GetViewForSupplementaryElement(UICollectionView collectionView, NSString elementKind, NSIndexPath indexPath)
   {
       var headerView = (Header)collectionView.DequeueReusableSupplementaryView(elementKind, headerId, indexPath);
       headerView.Text = "Supplementary View";
       return headerView;
   }
   ```

Just tested these steps here and they work in my sample app (based on https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-11-KittenView_Collections).

---

Aside> There is an open issue to provide bindable supplementary views - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/339 - but this issue shouldn't effect the basic collection view operation.

Comment: Thanks Stuart.  Much appreciated.  I tested this in a separate project, which is really just a copy of the SimpleCollectionView sample from Xamarin, and it worked fine.  That said, I'm still having the same problem with my working project - GetViewForSupplementaryView is never being called.  I'll have to keep trying to chase down the issue.  But I can (re)confirm that the method above works.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem when using MvvmCross, MvxCollectionViewController never call to

> public override UICollectionReusableView
>   GetViewForSupplementaryElement

and I resolved the problem using the answer of "Perfem_element".

```
public class MyCollectionViewSource: MvxCollectionViewSource
{

public MyCollectionViewSource(UICollectionView collectionView, NSString defaultCellIdentifier) : base(collectionView, defaultCellIdentifier)
{
}

public override UICollectionReusableView GetViewForSupplementaryElement(UICollectionView collectionView, NSString elementKind, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var headerView = (MyHeader)collectionView.DequeueReusableSupplementaryView(elementKind, MyHeader.Key, indexPath);
    headerView.Text = "Supplementary View";
    return headerView;
}
```

and finally in MvxViewController:

```
var source = new MyCollectionViewSource (CollectionView, ListadoCollectionCell.Key);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with MvvmCross. I was able to solve it by subclassing the MvxCollectionViewSource class and overriding the GetViewForSupplementaryElement method:

```
public class MyCollectionViewSource: MvxCollectionViewSource
{
    public TimelineSource(UICollectionView collectionView, NSString defaultCellIdentifier) : base(collectionView, defaultCellIdentifier)
    {
    }

    public override UICollectionReusableView GetViewForSupplementaryElement(UICollectionView collectionView, NSString elementKind, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var headerView = (MyHeader)collectionView.DequeueReusableSupplementaryView(elementKind, MyHeader.Key, indexPath);
        headerView.Text = "Supplementary View";
        return headerView;
    }
}
```